# R, how to use the content of a variable as the name of a field of a list?

Tags: r, list, variable-assignment, data-manipulation

I'm working in [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I would like to allocate a [list](/questions/tagged/list) field having the name of the content of a variable. In the following example, I would like that a field of the list `this_list` was called `bbb` and had value `2`, but I get several mistakes by using both `paste()` and `eval(quote())`:

```
var <- "bbb"

this_list <- list()
this_list$aaa <- 1

this_list$paste(var) <- 2
Error: attempt to apply non-function

this_list$eval(quote(var)) <- 2
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

My desired output is:

```
str(this_list)
List of 2
 $ aaa: num 1
 $ bbb: num 2
```

Can someone help me and tell me the right command to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$`, use `[[` for evaluating the object

```
this_list[[var]] <- 2
this_list
#$aaa
#[1] 1

#$bbb
#[1] 2
```